# Given a URL of an image, how do I upload that image to the Facebook user's album?

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload photo to users profile from photo URL, not input file field](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7934999/upload-photo-to-users-profile-from-photo-url-not-input-file-field)

I have the access_token. It's with the `publish_stream` permission.

Alright, now I want to upload an image to my default app's album on Facebook.   The image is hosted on my S3.amazon.com. (but for example purposes, let's take this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvlWa.jpg)

How can I upload this imgur image to my app's album? (documentation on Facebook is weird, and I don't understand PHP).

Comment: what is the problem with the current answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload photo to "Application Album" you have two ways (actually first may interest you more).

**Option 1:** [Uploading Photos to the Graph API via a URL](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/):

> App developers who host their images on Amazon S3 or a similar service can **pass the S3 URL directly to Facebook without having to download the file to their application servers only to upload it again to Facebook**. This improves performance and reduces costs for developers.

To achieve this you need to issue `POST` request (or `GET` with argument `method=post`) to next URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?
       access_token=...&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FPtyzk.jpg
```

`http://i.imgur.com/Ptyzk.jpg` in url encoded form is `http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FPtyzk.jpg` (you only need to encode `url` if you passing it withing URL arguments, and must not encode  if you passing it with post-data).

As stated in [`photo` object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), by posting photo to `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos`:

> The photo will be published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded this way will then be added to this same album.

**Option 2:** Uploading image data

You just need to issue `POST` request to `http://graph.facebook.com/me/photos` (see [Create Photos section of `user` object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos)).

The only required parameter is `source` which is `multipart/form-data` encoded file, you can either download it to temporary file and upload it later, or stream it to the Graph API (depending on technology you use to implement this functionality)

There is couple of samples how to upload photo (in languages other than PHP):

- [Android SDK samples (Hackbook)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/Hackbook.java#L146)
- [Facebook C# SDK (on Codeplex)](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Upload-Progress.aspx)

**Update:**
It's not really clear where do you want photo to be published User's album or Application album (`title` and `body` of question are opposite on this). If you want to publish it to User's album you need to replace `me` with `id` of album you want photo be uploaded to. Otherwise use `me` (for current user) or other user `id` (this will require usage of [application `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin)).

Comment: This is spot on! Option 1 is what I was looking for. And you wrote a perfect answer, thank you! I wish I could give you the bounty, but the question's closed. how do I give you the bounty? If you re-open this, I can give you the bounty

Comment: @TIMEX, if this question will be reopened or it's answers merged with other question you can [do it manually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69592/is-it-possible-to-award-a-bounty-to-or-otherwise-reward-an-exceptional-answer) if you wish ;)

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial does exactly that:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

You can choose which album you want to upload the picture to.

If you want to do it on a more generic way, Facebook API tells you to issue a POST request to  ALBUM_ID/photos with `source` and `message` parameters. Note that `source` must be of multipart/form-data type.

More details at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Comment: What are the POST parameters?  Because I get "Requires upload file" when I send the POSt request

Comment: By the way, the tutorial shows a <form> with ACTION to the facebook url. That's not what I want. I want to upload to Facebook using my backend

Comment: updated answer to be more generic and linked to documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think the majority of this answers are correct if you would like to upload that photo to a user of your app. But as I understand you want to upload it to your app's connected album. To do that you should get you app album's id than you'll be able to post an image to it like:

`$facebook->api('album_id', 'POST', array(...`

To get the id of the album go to the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and do a GET to: /your_app_id/albums (replace your_app_id with your actual app id). That should give you all the details about your app albums. Than do a Graph API POST request using your preferred SDK (JS, PHP etc.) with the array containing the picture source and a title (this are mandatory) to the above address.

NOTICE: The album application connection is deprecated and will be removed on March 1st, 2012. Read more at the end of this doc http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: Actually posting image to `/me/photos` will add em to Application Album (creating it if album not yet exists)

Comment: @juicy Can you give me a link stating this because I really think you're wrong. /me/photos is the path for the currently loged in user. I can give a reference: [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) read this: "Additionally, there is a special identifier me which refers to the current user. So the URL https://graph.facebook.com/me returns the active user's profile."

Comment: voila, [`photo` object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Comment: Same statement you can find in [How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload Photos to a user’s profile](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) developers blog post which is referenced here in answers. Added that to my answer for clarification. BTW, 
Sure you need to replace `me` with `id` of user you want for posting photo to profile other than current user (you should use application `access_token` for that).

Comment: I'd advice you to read again the question : "How can I upload this imgur image to my app's album?"

Comment: App's album is not the same with user album ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7197/discussion-between-juicy-scripter-and-alexandru-savin)